# Images from external volume on docker return ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE

Tags: wordpress, docker-compose, cifs, volumes, http-0.9

I'm running a docker-compose containing wordpress and an external volume on a different server `//yyy.yyy.y.yyy/wptest/docker_wordpress` where I'm storing contents from the uploads folder.

Writing and reading media on the file system works just fine, after having set the proper uid and gid settings in the ext-storage.

However, accessing resources via `http (for ex. http://localhost:8000/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/myimage.png )` returns a `ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE`

on curling the image url it returns:
Received `HTTP/0.9` when not allowed

This is the docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"
    
services:
    
  wordpress:
    
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      - wordpress_data:/var/www/html
      - ext-storage:/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads:rw
            
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: "xxx.xxx.x.xxx:3306"
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: "docker_wordpress"
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: "xxxxxxxxxxx"
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: "docker_wordpress"
            
volumes:
  db_data: {}
  wordpress_data: {}

  ext-storage:
    driver_opts:
      type: "cifs"
      o: "username=xxxx,password=xxxx,uid=33,forceuid,gid=33,forcegid,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755"
      device: "//yyy.yyy.y.yyy/wptest/docker_wordpress"
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by adding EnableMMAP Off to the vhost config file in docker.

Open terminal and type:

```
docker exec -it <docker-id> /bin/bash
```

Then you'll need to edit 000-default.conf

If you don't have vim installed

```
apt-get update
apt-get install vim


vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf


   <VirtualHost *:80>
   ....
    
    #EnableSendfile Off
    EnableMMAP Off

...
```

restart Apache

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

I'm still wondering how to add EnableMMAP Off in docker-compose.yml though.